# ExchangeManagementShell - How to get EdbFilePath and LogFolderPath... of all copies of MailboxDatabase (please note-interested in all copies)?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

How to get DatabaseCopy's EdbFilePath and LogFolderPath information?

Please see from below i can able to get the information for MailboxDatabase. But not for MailboxDatabaseCopies?

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$md | select name, edbfilepath, LogFolderPath, logfileprefix

Name                          EdbFilePath                   LogFolderPath                 LogFilePrefix
----                          -----------                   -------------                 -------------
Mailbox Database 1653755753   C:\Program Files\Microsoft... C:\Program Files\Microsoft... E00

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$md.gettype().fullname
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.MailboxDatabase
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$mdc = $md.DatabaseCopies[0]
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$mdc | select name, edbfilepath, LogFolderPath, logfileprefix

name                          edbfilepath                   LogFolderPath                 logfileprefix
----                          -----------                   -------------                 -------------

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$mdc.gettype().fullname
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.DatabaseCopy

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$mdc

DatabaseName         : Mailbox Database 1653755753
HostServerName       : NAG1-HRV-VM-R2
ActivationPreference : 1
ParentObjectClass    : msExchPrivateMDB
ReplayLagTime        : 00:00:00
TruncationLagTime    : 00:00:00
AdminDisplayName     :
ExchangeVersion      : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
DistinguishedName    : CN=NAG1-HRV-VM-R2,CN=Mailbox Database 1653755753,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (
                       FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=NagExchange2010,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,C
                       N=Configuration,DC=nagdc,DC=esi,DC=emc,DC=com
Identity             : Mailbox Database 1653755753\NAG1-HRV-VM-R2
Guid                 : 175a24db-426c-47a1-8ad6-ff5ae6b56aca
ObjectCategory       : nagdc.esi.emc.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-MDB-Copy
ObjectClass          : {top, msExchMDBCopy}
WhenChanged          : 1/7/2013 7:28:45 PM
WhenCreated          : 1/7/2013 7:28:45 PM
WhenChangedUTC       : 1/8/2013 3:28:45 AM
WhenCreatedUTC       : 1/8/2013 3:28:45 AM
OrganizationId       :
OriginatingServer    : NAG3-HRV-VM-R2.nagdc.esi.emc.com
IsValid              : True

Regards,

Dreamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979782(v=exchg.141).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979782%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

The *copies* of a DAG database cannot be on separate paths.  That is why there is no way to specify it when adding a *copy* of a database (you must specify paths when *creating* databases, however).  Once established, you cannot change the paths of an individual copy.  If you do change it for the database, the path must exist on all servers that will hold a copy.

Thus, to answer your question, the first query you ran in your example shows the path for logs and databases of the active and all passive copies.

Answer (score 0):

The title says you'd like to get the file/folder paths of the EDB and logs, but I think you already found that (from the first example).

If you'd like to get the folder path of the database copies (of a DAG), they are the same as the 'primary' database.

DAG database and log *paths* MUST be the same on all servers that hold a copy of the database (although the underlying storage does not need to be the same).

Comment: Thanks BHall. But, all the database copies of mailbox database in DAG need not have same database(edb) and logfoder paths. For ex: using Move-DatabasePath cmdlet database paths can be moved.